# Poetic two-character words of the form: Verb + Natural Noun?

Tags: mandarin, vocabulary, verbs, classical-chinese, poetry

I was looking for examples in Mandarin of poetic two-character words. What words have the following form...

> Verb + Noun

...where the noun is something that occurs in nature?

The first examples that spring to mind for me are 赏月 and 踏青.

Comment: the "verb+noun" pattern is common to see in Chinese words, but what do you mean by "poetic" in the title of the question? to be "poetic" would be subjective in my opinion.

Comment: (1) It's more than verb+noun; it's verb + *natural* noun. (2) Yes, "poetic" is a subjective term; interpret as you see fit.

Comment: I voted to close this question for two reasons: 1) it is too broad even when limited to poetic two characters verb + natural noun; 2) few users, if any, would be looking for such poetic two characters verb + natural noun for this question to be of useful value. Others who voted to close may have their own reasons.. Due to the open and voluntary nature of the moderating community, some may be more lenient while others more strict, but rest assured that there is nothing personal about it. You can try to ask this on Meta as it would be a better venue for such discussion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Everything can be poetic, especially Chinese write all kinds of poems ...

## Part I - Nature/Astronomy

### Nature 自然

```
乘风 乘風 Ride the Wind
破浪 破浪 Break the Eave

拈花 拈花 Touching Flower

采花 採花 Picking Flower
扑蝶 撲蝶 Catching Butterfly

看海 看海 Watch | Look | Admire the Sea
听涛 聽濤 Listen to the Wave

落花 落花 Flower Dropping 
流水 流水 Flowing Water
开花 開花 Blossom
结果 結果 Have Fruit

煮海 煮海 Boil the Sea
焚天 焚天 Burn the Sky

毀天 毀天 Destroy the Sky
灭地 滅地 Destroy the Ground/Earth(crust)
```

### Astronomy 天象

```
追风 追風 Chasing the Wind
逐月 逐月 After the Moon
追星 追星 Chasing Star
逐日 逐日 After the Sun
摘星 摘星 Picking Star (as in Picking Flower)
采月 採月 Picking the Moon (as in Picking Flower)
奔月 奔月 Run to the Moon
赏月 賞月 Moon watching
观星 觀星 Star Gazing 
观天 觀天 Sky Watching
登天 登天 Ascend to the Sky/Haven
```

## Part II - Extra

### Daily Live 日常生活

```
修桥 修橋 Fixing Bridge
补路 補路 Repair Road
杀人 殺人 Killing People
放火 放火 Burning Houses

杀人放火金腰带  殺人放火金腰帶
修桥补路无尸骸  修橋補路無屍骸

    Those who kill
        who burn
            Wear a golden belt

    Those who build
        who fix
            Have no remains (Die and body not found)

登顶 登頂 Ascend to Top(Mountain)
登极 登極 Ascend to Top(Thrown)
上台 上台 Get on Stage / Win a seat (Political)
落台 落台 Lost the seat/position (Political)
落幕 落幕 Closing/End (Performance/Situation)

画眉 畫眉 Put on make up (specific for eyebrow)
弄妆 弄妝 Put on make up
添妆 添壯 Put on make up
```

### Yin Yan Elements 陰陽五行

```
溶金 溶金 Melting Metal
生木 生木 Growing Wood
納水 納水 Absorbing Water
炼火 煉火 Refining Fire
归土 歸土 Returning to Earth
化阴 化陰 Digesting negative energy
```

### Animal 飛禽走獸

```
骑虎 騎虎 Riding Tiger
骑鹤 騎鹤 Riding Crane
```

### Direction 方向

```
东进 東進 Enter/Move towards east
东来 東來 Come to the east (from west)
西去 西去 Go west
北上 北上 Go up north
南下 南下 Go down south
归西 歸西 Return west (also mean dying / death)
```

### Time 時間

```
不长命 不長命 Don't live long
留千年 留千年 Remain for millennium
```

## Part III - Bonus

When we say `poem`, or `poetic`, we offend associate the term with *beautiful*, *romantic*, *relax*, all the positive side of life.

However, a lot of famous Chinese poem has nothing to do with the above. They are good, excellent poem. Their wording are beautiful (詞藻幽美/華麗), but not the scene they describe. They present some dark reality in a poetic form. Following are two examples

### Poem about deep disparity between the rich and the poor

```
朱門酒肉臭    朱门酒肉臭
路有凍死骨    路有冻死骨
 (唐 杜甫)     (唐 杜甫)

    朱門 朱門 Red Door / Red Gate. In the past, only the wealthy can paint their door in red
    酒肉 酒肉 Wine and meat / Food
    臭   臭   Giving out rotten smell

    路有 路有 On the road / On the side of the road / On the ground / On the floor
    冻死 凍死 Die from coldness / Freeze to death
    骨   骨   Bone / Dead Bodies

Rotten food at wealthy door
Frozen bodies on the floor
(by Du Fu, Tang Dynasty)
```

### Poem about courage and wish, disappointment and helplessness of a General

```
怒髮衝冠 憑欄處            怒发冲冠 凭栏处
瀟瀟雨歇 抬望眼            潇潇雨歇 抬望眼
仰天長嘯 壯懷激烈          仰天长啸 壮怀激烈

三十功名 塵與土            三十功名 尘与土
八千里路 雲和月            八千里路 云和月
莫等閑 白了少年頭 空悲切    莫等闲 白了少年头 空悲切

靖康恥 猶未雪             靖康耻 犹未雪
臣子恨 何時滅             臣子恨 何时灭
駕長車 踏破賀蘭山缺        驾长车 踏破贺兰山缺

壯志飢餐 胡虜肉            壮志饥餐 胡虏肉
笑談渴飲 匈奴血            笑谈渴饮 匈奴血
待從頭 收拾舊山河 朝天闕    待从头 收十旧山河 朝天阙
  (宋 岳飛)                  (宋 岳飞)
```

There is an extremely good translation [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_Jiang_Hong). I cannot beat that.

## PS1

Previously included, but removed after review (Thanks NS.X for pointing out)

```
朝花 朝花 Morning Flower | Blossoming in the Morning
夕拾 夕拾 Picking Flower in Evening
```

The two do not meet OP required Verb+Noun formation, not even in reverse order. (I have to read like 6 times to realize it >.< )

## PS2

[Tradition/Simplified Chinese Conversion Web Site](http://www.ecj.hk/translate/translate.aspx)

Comment: This is an elaborated answer but op explicitly asked for V+N phrases. Besides 修桥/铺路/杀人/放火 is hardly poetic in common contexts.

Comment: LOL, down vote for what reason? :P I will give you example for that!!

Comment: 朝花/夕拾 are not V+N phrases. 采花 is used in poems but can be also used in colloquial language without bringing any poetic effect; 拈花 would be a better example.

Comment: Correct, some of them are in reverse form of what OP is asking. Especially the `Direction` section.

Comment: `朝花` should be translated to `Blossom in the morning`, `Blossom` is used as a verb.(開花, flower opening up), not a noun.

Comment: 拈花 is good example. Updated.

Comment: So a lot of this is irrelevant for my question, but I up-voted nonetheless. Would still like to see a detailed answer that directly responds to the constraints in my question. Also, is there a way to convert all characters in someone else's answer to simplified? Reading 繁体字 is something I only do at KTVs (and even then begrudgingly so).

Comment: hmm, ok, you are looking specific for `Nature`. I missed that part. My bad. Then only `Nature` and `Astronomy` section fit your requirement.

Comment: @B.D you tagged your question with "Classical Chinese" but are unwilling to read Reading 繁體字? Riiiiight...

Comment: Reformatted to fit original question. SC TC side by side to fit everyone eyes. Happy Holiday!!!!

Comment: @dda I have not studied traditional characters, but can read simplified characters quickly and easily. I think it's possible that there are verbs that were used in classical Chinese which would fit the bill nicely. Unfortunately, when I see 觀星 I have no idea what the first character is.

Comment: @B.D I will consider this (TC/SC) in future, but properly will depends on length and format. The format of this answer was just pain to re-do. I was pasting/copying(I cannot type SC) line by line. Maybe I will just post them into separate section next time. And yes, I have to agree, some TC and SC just look way too different, I have difficulty read SC sometimes.

Comment: @JohnSiu I didn't intend for you to go through something that tedious (thanks again!) but rather wondered whether the site had a feature (or could implement a feature) in which one can switch all characters on a page between SC and TC (similar to what Wikipedia has).

Comment: @B.D The wiki way is a very good point, we should bring it up in meta.